# Adjust column width of specific row

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I have one html table.

[image]

I had used `colResizable` plugin for adjust column width but it change width of entire column.

I want to adjust column of specific row like below image
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The whole column need to have the same width, you can't change one specific column's width from a certain row and expect the others to remain the same.

You need to use `<td colspan="x"></td>` for a column to be "wider" than the other columns from the same column, where `x` is the number of columns you want to merge.